# Python : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list

My program looks like

```
# global
item_to_bucket_list_map = {}

def fill_item_bucket_map(items, buckets):
    global item_to_bucket_list_map

    for i in range(1, items + 1):
        j = 1
        while i * j <= buckets:
            if j == 1:
                item_to_bucket_list_map[i] = [j]
            else:
                item_to_bucket_list_map[i] = (item_to_bucket_list_map.get(i)).append(j)
            j += 1
        print "Item=%s, bucket=%s" % (i, item_to_bucket_list_map.get(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    buckets = 100
    items = 100
    fill_item_bucket_map(items, buckets)
```

When I run this, it throws me

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

Not sure why this would happen? When I am already creating a list at start of each `j`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually you stored `None` here:
`append()` changes the list in place and returns `None`

```
 item_to_bucket_list_map[i] = (item_to_bucket_list_map.get(i)).append(j)
```

example:

```
In [42]: lis = [1,2,3]

In [43]: print lis.append(4)
None

In [44]: lis
Out[44]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @DSM just checked, the `None` is not coming due to `get()`, `i` is present in the dict but it's  value is `None`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: you're right -- somehow I missed that it *would* loop multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

```
[...]
for i in range(1, items + 1):
    j = 1
    while i * j <= buckets:
        if j == 1:
            mylist = []
        else:
            mylist = item_to_bucket_list_map.get(i)
        mylist.append(j)
        item_to_bucket_list_map[i] = mylist
        j += 1
    print "Item=%s, bucket=%s" % (i, item_to_bucket_list_map.get(i))
```

The `while` loop, however, can be simplified to

```
    for j in range(1, buckets / i + 1): # + 1 due to the <=
        if j == 1:
            mylist = []
        else:
            mylist = item_to_bucket_list_map.get(i)
        mylist.append(j)
        item_to_bucket_list_map[i] = mylist
```